# Mail autocomplete is different for search and compose

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, contacts

It annoys me that Mail “To” field autocomplete doesn't match that of the search bar.

When I start typing name of a person **I've had conversation with** in the search bar, I can see their full name along with the address. Clearly, Mail knows about them.

[image: Mail search bar autocomplete]

When I hit Compose and start typing in “To” field, I see a tiny loading wheel image appearing on the right for a fraction of second—and then, nothing, no autocomplete, no suggestions.

[image: Mail compose autocomplete]

The search field looks among all the people you've ever talked to  but the compose form **only offers your address book contacts**.

Can I change it to work the same way as Search bar, or do I have to add each person in my address book to have them in autocomplete?

I'm using Gmail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in autocomplete stems from the fact there is no “Mail knows about”. The lookup happens on two different sets of data:

- Autocomplete in search happens on the **Spotlight index of all received and sent mails** in Mail.app’s database ([since version 2 of Mail.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_%28application%29)).
- Autocomplete on compose happens on Mail.app’s potential recipients list, which is a compound of **contacts with an email address in Addressbook** and **a list of previous recipients stored by Mail.app** (a [list you can see and edit](http://www.midwesternmac.com/tutorial/2009-01-05/taming-mac-os-x-mail-previous-recipients) under *Window » Previous Recipients*).

Notice the difference: search knows about people you have only received mail from, compose does not. Hence different autocomplete results.