# How can I edit a mistyped or incomplete recipient address in the ios mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

When trying to send a mail to a new recipient it quite often happens that I mistype it on the tiny iPhone onscreen keyboard or that I unintentionally touch the screen in a different field while typing, so it changes focus and there is a partial e-mail address in the To: field.

How can I correct it without retyping the whole address?

I tried moving the cursor inside it, but the whole address is selected and I can only  remove or replace it completely.

I also tried holding the finger on the address for a longer time, hoping that a menu appears, but that just selects it completely.

On macOS Mail, a little menu button appears next to such an e-mail address which has an entry that allows editing it.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS mail app address field doesn’t obey the conventions for an editable/autosuggestable/autocorrectable text entry. It [follows the design of macOS mail from back when it was called OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29709/5472).

Once you move off the typing on 15.3.1 and below it gets converted into an object and is no longer text that is editable.

[image: iOS 15 mail address to field with foo foo foo text]

The only thing you can do is compose the addresses in another app. Quick notes on iPad is better than on iPhone - but you can get it from control center and leverage data detectors.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/take-notes-iph1ac0b3a2/ios
- https://www.imore.com/how-use-instant-notes-iphone-and-ipad

Or use the contact app and allow auto complete to reduce taps when adding contacts that are now known.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly asked question. I tested this for sometime, I had the same issue. This is not present as a feature for now.

I believe it is a pending feature for iOS.

A solution from another world though :=> copy pasting an address is much more efficient and editable. Even if you made a mistake, you can always paste again and edit.